# To find the minimum value of $|z−w|$ where $z, w ∈ \Bbb C$ such that $|z| = 11$, and $|w+4+3i| = 5$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

To find the minimum value of $|z−w|$ where $z, w ∈ \Bbb C$ such that $|z| = 11$, and $|w+4+3i| = 5$. 
Options are:

$(A) 1.$

$(B) 2.$

$(C) 5.$

$(D) 6.$

I have thought a solution of it but it is lengthy:

Let $z=x+iy$ and $w = p+iq$ and we use method of Lagrange Multipliers to minimize $f(x,y,p,q) = \sqrt{(x-p)^2+(y-p)^2}$ subject to the constraints $g(x,y,p,q) = x^2+y^2-121=0$ and $h(x,y,p,q) = (p+4)^2+(q+3)^2-25 =0$.

Another approach is intuitive but I have a doubt if it is correct:

The points which satisfy $|z| = 11$ lie on a circle of radius $11$ in $\Bbb C$ and $|w+4+3i| = 5$  is the circle centered at $(−4,−3)$ of radius $5$ and it is contained in $|z| = 11$. So the minimum distance is $11-10=1$.

Is the method Correct? Or please suggest a good approach.

Comment: your geometric approach is definitely the best, and you get the correct answer really easily.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use triangle inequality i use it for minimum,maximum so $|\omega|+|4+3i|\geq |\omega +4+3i|$ thus $0\leq |\omega|\leq 10$ thus $|z-\omega|\geq |z|-|\omega|$ thus for maxima we have $|z|-|\omega|=11-10=1$